# GetFileFromPathAsync giving "The parameter is incorrect" exception

Tags: exception, windows-10, win-universal-app

I've started to get into Windows Universal Platform programming (Windows 10, VS2015, c#) and hitting some basic issues..

I have a subfolder in MusicLibrary with a file test.txt in it. At the moment I am forcing GetFileFromPathAsync to be non asych (I'm in early stage of converting an old app to new target so asynch will come in later). Based on some examples the following code should work

```
            string parentPath = returnStorage(_location).Path;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(parentPath, _filename);
            StorageFile _file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But I'm getting the exception "The parameter is incorrect" but I cannot understand why

```
_filename = "ggmptest_04a\\test.txt"
parentPath = ""
_location is musicLibrary
```

Elsewhere in my code I am able to create subfolders and files to musicLibrary and list files there with GetItemsAsync.. But this GetFileFromPathAsync call fails me..

Please, what is the obvious that everybody else sees immediately -- but evades now my eyes.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetFileFromPathAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) throws `ArgumentException` if the provided path is not an absolute path.

In your case, seems like that the `filePath` contains a relative path since `parentPath` is an empty string and combining it with `_filename` will result a relative path.

Comment: Thanks.. But then, how do I actually get an absolute path to KnownFolders.MusicLibrary? Or is it a thing that is not possible at all as suggested here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab55de1c-7f0a-425b-99e2-260446a0d189/knownfoldersmusiclibrarypath-returns-0null?forum=winappswithnativecode

Comment: @juhariis If you create a file or folder in known folder, its Path property will be valid but I'm not should whether you can rely on that path or just rely on the returned item.

Comment: Okay - I'm marking your response as answer. Based on the link above to social.msdn.microsoft.com it appears they do not even want people to use absolute paths to places like MusicLibrary so I'll think my use case differently. The other places I need to use ( Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder and Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder) work fine.

Comment: Furthermore, I found now, when rechecking MusicLibrary again, a clear error message in the Output panel of VS2015 that I had somehow overlooked / not noticed before "WinRT information: The specified path (ggmptest_t02\test.txt) is not an absolute path, and relative paths are not permitted."